# Асинхронное воспроизведение звука на питоне

Tags: python, tkinter, аудио, playsound

Я создаю программу на питон которая считает нажатие на кнопку , проще говоря счётчик, когда я не использую воспроизведение звука то всё нормально но когда я добавил что при нажатии на кнопку воспроизводится звук то чтобы ещё раз нажать на кнопку надо ждать пока закончится и звук , и это очень неудобно , то есть мне надо сделать так что воспроизведение звука выполняется асинхронно , но никак не получается.

Вот сам код

```
def click_plus():
    click_sound()
    global clicks
    clicks = clicks+1
    label['text'] = str(clicks)
    playsound.playsound("zvuk11.mp3")
```

Comment: А пробовали: playsound.playsound("zvuk11.mp3", block = False ) ?

Comment: здраствуйте нет, ещё не пробовал , щас попробую спасибо на будущее